How do Area Solar Radiation in ArcGIS account for the solar intensity?
I read that the Area Solar Radiation accounts for the position of the sun throughout the year and at different times of day, obstacles that may block sunlight such as nearby trees or buildings, and the slope and orientation of the surface.
However, I haven’t read anything about how the tool accounts for the amount of solar energy (i.e. intensity) received by the area of interest.
I’m not sure if the the sunmap already accounts for it but I want to know how it accounts because as far as I have read, more on the topography and obstructions are considered.
Can you enlighten me?

I assume you are using ArcGIS Pro so I’ve added a tag for that.

Most likely it is potential maximum I.e. clouds free
